# Spring WebSockets join another chat room

Tags: java, spring

I have implemented a console application using Spring and WebSockets. The application works fine if one or more participants are connected to the base method which is anotated like this.

```
@MessageMapping("/chat")
@SendTo("/topic/messages")
```

I will copy the configuration and the implementation which i have made o be more clear.

```
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

}

@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public OutputMessage send(@Payload Message message) {
        return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText());
    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat/{room}")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages/{room}")
    public OutputMessage enableChatRooms(@DestinationVariable String room, @Payload Message message) {
        return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText());
    }

}

@Service
public class SessionHandlerService extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

    private String nickName;

    public SessionHandlerService() {
        this.nickName = "user";
    }

    private void sendJsonMessage(StompSession session) {
        ClientMessage msg = new ClientMessage(nickName, " new user has logged in.");
        session.send("/app/chat", msg);
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return ServerMessage.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        System.err.println(payload.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        session.subscribe("/topic/messages", new SessionHandlerService());
        sendJsonMessage(session);
    }
}
```

The problem which i face is that when i subscribe to `/topic/messages` and `session.send("/app/chat", msg);`everything works fine. But if i choose something like `session.send("/app/chat/room1", msg);` and `/topic/messages/room1` the participans can not see each other messages like they are in different chat rooms.